# Parity Signer qr code not working, stuck on "Parity Signer: Pending"

Tags: parity, parity-signer, qrcode

I'm having issues with with Parity when trying to do any type of transfer-I get stuck on the "parity signer: pending" screen. The prompt I get is "Please scan the transaction QR on your external device"  But when I scan, the qr code isn't recognized.

I have in the past successfully done transfers, though not sure if with the qr code signer however-it was a few months ago. My external device (phone) was lost, so not sure if this is part of the issue, as I'm using a new phone.

I'm running windows 10, google chrome, Parity v. 1.7, installed from Parity.io website. 
I feel I must be missing something quite obvious... 
Any help would be deeply appreciated, Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Do you have backups of your old phone's Ethereum keys or passphrase from the mobile signer app?

Comment: @5chdn No backups of my old phone's passphrase/keys from mobile signer app, unfortunately.

Comment: Not much you can do then. It's always sensible to backup your keys.